# What CMIS services are required if Fast Search is used to query an external CMIS repository

Tags: external-content-type, fast-search, query, cmis

For a repository to be CMIS compliant, it must implement a number of services. Query services are not mandatory. I want to incorporate a CMIS repository in SharePoint 2010 as an External Content Type. I then want to use Fast Search to find documents across both internal and external sources. Which CMIS services does Fast Search use to do its magic?